# HashMap ContainsKey vs contains

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a scenario like below.

I have a utility class with the foll. method.

```
public static Map<String, String> getFeeList() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Student Lists", "Student List");
        map.put("Student grade", "Student Grade");
        return map;
}
```

I am calling this method in the JSP and comparing it with another value like below,

feeListsMap below is nothing but `class.getFeeList()` set to request and retrieving in JSP.

```
<% if(feeListsMap.containsKey(vo.getSubClassDesc())){%>
<td align="center">0</td>       
<%}else{%>
<td align="center">TEST</td>        
<%}%>
```

From above `vo.getSubClassDesc()` may contain some suffixes like 'Student List as of today', 'Student List as of last month'...

But the above check in JSP will retrieve only exact key value and won't work for 'Student List as of today', 'Student List as of last month'.

I do not want to use substring here because the map may contain more key value pair and I do not want to use substring all the time.
Is there an easy way where I can compare the key value with the subClassDesc that works similar to String `contains()`?

Comment: hmmm can't u use String.contains("student") for each entry?

Comment: A HashMap uses the hash of a string, and not the string itself. So there's no way you can do what you're looking for. You can either transform the `vo.getSubClassDesc()` to match your key or get the `keySet()` and iterate through that keyset and use `vo.getSubClassDesc().contains(key)`

Comment: *Is there an easy way where I can compare the key value with the subClassDesc that works similar to String contains()?* With the current methods provided by Java built-in classes, no. You should traverse the keys in your map and do the `String#contains` as expected, and the easiness of this approach depends on the programmer (in this case, you). Probably you want to use a different structure to accomplish what you want/need.

Comment: From your example it seems you believe that "Student Lists" should match "Student List as of last month". How would you define your criterion exactly? A common prefix? Or did you make a mistake and the key should have been "Student Lists" and then the criterion is "key is a prefix of given string"?

Comment: @RealSkeptic...You are right...Key is a prefix of a given String in the above case "Student Lists" of the String "Student List as of last month"

Comment: If you can afford to use Guava, you can use an `Equivalence`

Comment: @fge..Yes i can use Guava. So can I use the same Hashmap and iterate or should I follow a different way. I have not used Guava though.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do it in built-in java classes. You must do

```
vo.getSubClassDesc().contains(key)
```

by looping on `feeListsMap` object's `key`s.